# CakePHP form input filed empty after get submit

Tags: cakephp, input, get

```
echo $this->Form->create('Driver', array('type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->end('Search');
```

as result $this->request:

```
query => array(
    'name' => 'some name'
)
```

Problem is input form is empty after search although `$this->request->query['name'] = 'some name'`
Everything works as expected when change form back to `post`

> Edit. Included the model and the controller. For testing I use clean install.
>   Model (Driver.php):

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Driver extends AppModel {
  public $displayField = 'name';
}
```

> Controller (DriversController.php):

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class DriversController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $drivers = $this->Driver->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('drivers'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your controller code for the action(s) being run.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller code you do not show us where you are trying to access the submitted form values so I will try and give some general information to get you moving.

To access your form data, you need to cool use request. To see exactly what is going on, enter in your controller one of the below...

```
print_r($this->request->data);
```

or

```
print_r($this->request);
```

Either of those will show you any data registered with CakePHP.

If you want to save this save using your Models. use...

```
$this->Driver->save($this->request->data)
```

You might want to check it is a post first though.. lets complete the code...

```
public function submit() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Driver->create();
        if ($this->Driver->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('FAILED');
        }
    }
}
```

The information above can be read in further detail [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#adding-posts).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear enough about the problem. The problem is not about processing the keyword. I can filter with 'conditions'. The problem is after the search when view rendered input (search) field is empty. For example when I type 'Adam' in search box, search box is empty after  page loaded again.

Comment: I will also suggest using debug() rather than print_r()

Comment: In your situation you probably do not need to see all the variable types, so var_dump will be too much information. print_r with <pre> would be much cleaner

Answer (score -1):

You can set form values by assigning to $this->data.

```
$this->data = $this->request->query;
```

Comment: Hmm, is it the expected behavior for 'get' forms that you need to assign input fields manually. I wonder if it was the same in earlier CakePHP versions.

Comment: `$this->data` is depreciated